# SQL amount of references to id in same table

Tags: sql, database, join, count

I need to know the amount of employees working for a person.
I am using a table with employee id's, employee names and id's of the person the employee is working for.
The result should be a table with the name of the person, and the amount of people working for him.

> +----+---------+------------------+
>   + id + name       + working for id+
>   + 1_+ joe__         + _______5___+
>   + 2_+ smith + _______5___+
>   + 3_+ alan_ + _______1___+
>   + 5_+ boss +______none___+

new table should be:

> +---------------+--------------------+
>   + name____ +  __amount____+
>   + joe______ + __1_________+
>   + boss____ + __2_________+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
select main_table.name,
       (select count(*) from employee as sub_table
        where sub_table.works_for_id = main_table.id) as amount
from employee as main_table
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's indeed what I needed